# DataTable filter expression with DateTime and less-or-equal operator problem

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            t.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            t.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
            DateTime tomorow = today.AddDays(1);

            t.Rows.Add(yesterday);
            t.Rows.Add(today);
            t.Rows.Add(tomorow);

            string filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "Date >= #{0}# AND Date <= #{1}#", yesterday, tomorow);

            t.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;

            foreach (DataRowView v in t.DefaultView)
                Console.WriteLine(v["date"]);
```

I'm expecting that the filtered `t.DefaultView` now contains all three "days". But for some reason the last date from the range isn't included. It seems `<=` operator for `DateTime` type works like a `<`.

Where is the problem? Is that a bug? Any suggestions how to overcome that?

**Update.**
Got some responses about `DateTime` type and comparison operators. Thanks.
But now I want to direct attention to [filter expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69c06922%28VS.71%29.aspx).
Ok, say I have the folloving loop:

```
foreach (DataRow r in t.Rows)
{
  DateTime date = (DateTime)r["Date"];
  if (yesterday <= date && date <= tomorow)
      Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

This loop should show the same result like

```
foreach (DataRowView v in t.DefaultView)
  Console.WriteLine(v["date"]);
```

from the previous example, yes? No! Here `<=` works as I'm expecting and the result is all three days. Why?

**Update #2: solution.**
As Joe has noted - the problem is about fractions of a second.
If I format upper and lower bounds with Round-trip date/time pattern (to preserve fractions of a second) - everything works just fine:

```
string filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "Date >= '{0}' AND Date <= '{1}'",
                yesterday.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                tomorow.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted in your update is not equivalent to the row filter.
Your row filter formats the date using the general format for the current culture.  This probably does not include fractions of a second - therefore unless you happen to call DateTime.Now on a second boundary, your `tomorrow` value will be some fractions of a second beyond the range specified by the filter.

I.e. if your `tomorrow` value is '2009-12-23 01:02:03.456', your row filter is only taking values up to and including '2009-12-23 01:02:03', a few fractions of a second before the value specified by tomorrow.

If you only want to compare dates, you should use DateTime.Date to truncate the time component from your dates (and use DateTime.Today rather than DateTime.Now for the current date).

Answer (score 2):

The date comparison takes the time into account. So, for instance, "today at midday" is greater than just "today". If you use `DateTime.Now`, the time is included. So, if `DateTime.Now` is "today at midday", then `tomorrow = today.AddDays(1)` is less than "tomorrow at 3PM"... So you need to ignore the time part of the date. You can do that by formatting the date without the time. Also, if you want to check that a date is "less or equal than tomorrow" (regardless of the time), check that it is "strictly less than the day after tomorrow" :

```
string filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "Date >= #{0:MM/dd/yyyy}# AND Date < #{1:MM/dd/yyyy}#",
                yesterday,
                tomorrow.AddDays(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

if does not solve, check whether your date field contains time also. there lies your problem.

Update: your second comment.

when you compare with DateTime.Now e.g. Date <= 21.12.2009 14:35:35, it will take all before 14:35 hours and will ignore later rows. Hope this helps you.

See following article to get more idea

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/06/understanding-datetime-and-timespan-in.html

Comment: Works fine when time not set (using DateTime.Today for example). But that is not enough.

Comment: What you've suggested - that's not the solution. That works when time is not set. But why it is not working with time? Why operator >= works and <= not? What I've posted here is just a test/example. I'm looking for more general explanation.